# CSS for Tab Panel

Tags: css, tabpanel

I want to have Tab panel like [this picture](http://www.uiwizards.com/portfolio_examples_images/DA_RolloutTab.jpg)

I want to implement the same on ASP.NET tab panel. However, if I get the CSS I would make it compatible to ASP.NET tab.

Can anyone please guide me how to do that, or tutorial reference. Because I don't know that what this tab panel CSS known as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely what you want (I don't know ASP).

But from what I understand, you can use [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and customize its CSS.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is awesome. But I am looking CSS something like this http://www.uiwizards.com/portfolio_examples_images/DA_RolloutTab.jpg

Comment: Look at this example: http://www.simplebits.com/bits/bulletproof_slants.html. He uses an image to the sloping sides.

Answer (score 1):

They are tricky to implement. Speaking only from CSS point of view, you will need to implement tab as

elements. Example

```
<ul>
<li>tab1<li>
<li>tab2</li>
...
</ul>
```

The rest of the design is just CSS. Since you have tringular tabs,so you will need background images.